# model tuning for Holt function

Tags: r, performance, time-series, holtwinters

I was working on `Holt` function from `"aTSA"` package.which having default of alpha = 0.2 and beta = 0.1057.I'm just wandering of how to change those alpha and beta(on what basis)to train the model for better forecasting for next 5 years.And the `type = c("additive","multiplicative")` which one is the best way to choose. Are there any blogs or some notes regarding these particularlt on `Holt's`(because when I tried I couldn't get the exact thing of what I need).

Comment: If you have a specific programming problem, it's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. If you need general advice about analyzing data or statistical models, then you should instead ask for help at [stats.se].